Can we make it clearer that you can retract and re-flag "moderator intervention" flags?
I raised a custom flag for an answer, and a few minutes later realised that the justification I had put in the flag was incorrect.
I still believe that the flag is correct (ChatGPT) but my justification is wrong.
I incorrectly believed that I couldn't retract and reflag, after reading:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

You cannot raise the same type of flag twice on a post: for example,
if you retract a "spam" flag, you won't be able to raise a spam flag
or an abusive flag in the future.
Retract flags only when you're sure there's no need for the post to be
flagged, or you become convinced that a more serious type of flag is
needed.

Can we improve the documentation?

If you raised an "in need of moderator intervention" flag, then you can definitely retract it and re-raise a new "in need of moderator intervention" flag with different contents. I've done it many times on many posts on multiple sites (i.e., sites where I'm not a moderator). I've done it more than once on a single post. Basically, if you don't currently have an active flag raised on that post, you can raise a new "in need of moderator intervention" flag on that post as long as you are able to raise a post flag (i.e., you're not out of flags or blocked from flagging).

I generally agree with this, but would like some clarity from moderators. I've asked and been informed by a moderator in chat before that retracting and reflagging generally won't disrupt their work. What I want to ask is whether an edited flag (if this feature request were to be implemented) would instead result in some confusion?

@AbdulAzizBarkat while I thought this was a new feature, you can in fact retract and re-flag "In need of moderator intervention" flags.

@tgdavies I am aware of that if you see the "retracting and reflagging generally won't disrupt their work" (The concern when I'd asked that was I'd already retracted a flag twice after finding more information and was heading for a third time). The concern I have in my previous comment though is whether making this proposed change would cause any hiccups in the moderators workflow. Although from what I understand the moderator tooling around this would benefit from a complete overhaul.

Allowing editing is worse overall, as there are more potential race conditions (e.g., moderator marking a flag helpful or declined based on the old version of an edited flag which hasn't, yet, been updated on the moderator's machine). With retracting and reflagging, the worst case is that the moderator is now working on a retracted flag. A moderator marking it helpful or declined has no effect. The moderator may still act on the post or user, but that would be based on what the mod sees independent of the flag. Then the new replacement flag is handled by either the same or a different mod.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I see your point - I was conflating retract/reflag with edit.

I think you should ask for an edit to the help page.

After getting a flag declined for AI garbage with wrong second person/third person indirect reference usage and claim to have tried code that could not compile because it references symbols removed in .NET 8; I don't think this is worth the trouble anymore. I think the moderator read the answer after edit rather than before.
